# How can I quickly delete a value of less than two characters from a large array?

Tags: php, performance

I want delete values of less than two characters from a my large array which have 9436065 string values. I deleted with `preg_grep()` using this code:

```
function delLess($array, $less)
{
    return preg_grep('~\A[^qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]{'.$less.',}\z~u', $array);
}

$words = array("ӯ","ӯро","ӯт","ғариб","афтода","даст", "ра");

echo "<pre>";
print_r(delLess($words,2));
echo "</pre>";
```

But it works slower. Is it possible to optimize this code?

Comment: You could use `isset($word[1])` but that won't work reliably for multibyte strings, e.g. it would remove "pa". Where do you get the array from in the first place? Can you already filter it at the source instead?

Comment: Answers could certainly get better if we had more information about the use and origin of those strings. Limiting us to just what we know now, I don't see a reason to change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function, performance should be better.

```
function filter($var)
{
  return strlen($var) > 2;
}

$newArray = array_filter($array, "filter"));
```

Comment: also acceptable, also downvoted, looks like people just like "disliking stuff" wtf man...

Answer (score -1):

given the size of the dataset, I'd use a database, so it would probably look like this:

```
delete from table where length(field) <= 2
```

maybe something like sqlite?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the strlen function instead of regular expressions and see if that is faster. (Or mb_strlen for multibyte characters.)

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($words as $val)
    if(strlen($val) > 2)
        $newArr[] = $val;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: why was this downvoted? I think it is an acceptable answer? I don't understand man...

Answer (score -1):

Any work on 10 million strings will take time. In my opinion, this kind of operation is a one timer, so it does not really matter if it is not instantaneous.

Where are the strings coming from? You certainly got them from a database, if so, do the work on the database it will be faster and at least you will not be polluted with them ever. This kind of operation will be faster on a database than PHP, but could still take time.

Again, if it is stored in a database, it has not got there magically... So you could also make sure that no new unwanted entry gets in it, that way you make sure this operation will not need to be redone.

I am aware that this absolutely does not answer your question at all, because we should stick to PHP and you got the best way to do it... Optimizing such a simple function would cost a lot of time and wouldn't bring much if any optimization... The only other suggestion I could make is use another tool, if not database-based, file-based like sed, awk or anything that reads/writes to files... You'd have one string per line and parse the file reducing its size accordingly, but writing the file from PHP, exec the script and load the file back in PHP would make things too complicated for nothing...

Comment: Words are taken from the `form` from the user's side or from an external `file`(doc, docx) to be added to the database. And this function is necessary for removing unwanted words that are less than `2 characters`. @Salketer

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. when you say less than 2 characters, is it ANY characters? Because in your OP it does not seem so... Also, are the words to be stored separately or together in one field?

Comment: Here we are talking only about words that consists of letters. @Salketer

Comment: List of letters:`a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯқғӯҳҷӣҚҒӮҲҶӢ`